# PHP Session timed-out but AJAX calls still worked

Tags: php, ajax, session-variables

I created an internal web-application on a localhost box using Apache, PHP, MySQL.

A user was using it and left it open in his browser window overnight. When he came back to the application and started using it again, he did not get a time out message until he tried to navigate away from the page, which is fine (and desired) but the page he was on has many AJAX pieces and he was able to use (call) ajax pages and get them to come up without a problem! He thought he was doing work but when he finally navigated to another page in the application it booted to the log in screen and he hadn't saved anything.

As soon as he called an AJAX page I would like the application to check if there is a session id and boot back to the log in page if there isn't one found. How can I do that?

Each AJAX page is its own PHP page and at the very top of the page there is call to **session_start();** and them immediately after there is a call to a custom function to check if the user is logged by looking for the presence of a certain session variable. Shouldn't that have not found the session varaible and then redirected as necessary or does that try to create a brand new session if it doesn't find one?

I need something like a session_continue rather than session_start.

Here is an excerpt from the php.ini file that has relevant session information.

```
; Whether to use cookies.
   session.use_cookies = 1

; Define the probability that the 'garbage collection' process is started
; on every session initialization.
; The probability is calculated by using gc_probability/gc_divisor,
; e.g. 1/100 means there is a 1% chance that the GC process starts
; on each request.

session.gc_probability = 1
session.gc_divisor     = 1000

; After this number of seconds, stored data will be seen as 'garbage' and
; cleaned up by the garbage collection process.
session.gc_maxlifetime = 28888
```

Comment: If there is ajax on the page, each ajax request should reset whatever session timeout there is. If by chance the session did timeout and an ajax event happened, it is possible that they were redirected to another page on ajax request (login page most likely) and the ajax response was not what was expected an caused an error in javascript stopping whatever ajax timer you have.

Comment: sorry it is I updated the questions a little, as soon as session_start is called, immediately after another function called check_logged_in is called and that looks for the presence of a $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true. If it doesn't find that it redirects to the log in page. Every page in the application contains that function to check if they are logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting a new session without checking whether the old has expired, you need to check first before issuing a `start_session()`.

You can do this quite easy by checking whether there is still a session cookie send by the client (usually `PHPSESSION` as long as you did not change the name). Once this has expired, the current (last) session is gone and user needs to log in again.

In order to handle this properly and to summarize the above comments, you first of all need:

1. check, if there's a session running
2. check, if in the running session, a user has been authenticated
3. check if this user is granted to submit the current action

If one of these checks fails, redirect him to the login screen. You may then terminate any running session and start a new with a new session ID in order to get rid of old data.

What you have done so far in php.ini is nothing but setting up garbage collection for old session data. This is the last to do. "Using cookies" will not handle logins e.a. for your application which currently is open like a barn door to any one entering ("attack" is the wrong word).

Comment: This is along the lines of what I want to do. Can you point me to any resources for this? According to my PHP.ini file I am already using session cookies.

Comment: Another problem I have was that in php.ini,  session.cookie_lifetime was set to 0, meaning it expires upon browser restart, whereas the session garbage collection max lifetime was set to 8 hours, so the browser says indefinitely, but server says 8 hours. that was the problem. Should I set those values to be equal times?